# Sending an email from FormHandler

Tags: symfony

I have been reading quite a lot of documentation on how to inject services, etc but still haven't found a simple solution for my problem.

The problem is : accessing the mailer service from the FormHandler. When the form is valid, it sends an email, simple as that.

The thing is i have to pass the mailer as a parameter each time i call the FormHandler, which i think is not really clean.

**So, how can i access the mailer service from the FormHandler without all this parameters stuff ?**

Here is where i am:

```
 $formHandler = new InscriptionHandler($form,
                                          $this->get('request'),
                                          $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager(),
                                          $this->get('mailer'),
                                          $this,
                                          $this->getRequest()->getLocale());
```

and then, the constructor :

```
        public function __construct(Form $form, Request $request, EntityManager $em, $sm, $ctrl, $locale) {
        $this->form    = $form;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->em      = $em;
        $this->sm      = $sm;
        $this->ctrl    = $ctrl;
        $this->locale  = $locale;
    }
```

I guess i could just pass $this as a parameter but for a better understanding of the problem, that's the code i have written.

Thanks in advance,
James

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to define  service first like this

```
# app/config/config.yml
services:
    my_mailer:
        class:        Acme\HelloBundle\Mailer
        arguments:    [sendmail]
```

The you can use like this

```
$mailer = $this->get('my_mailer');
$mailer->send('ryan@foobar.net', ...);
```

Look here for more info

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Comment: the problem is the get method is only accessible from a Controller object and not from outside controllers unfortunately

Comment: you can get the $mailer in controller and then pass it as argument during the form generation in constructor

Comment: yes that's what i'm doing but i was wondering if there wasn't an easier way to do this

Comment: The other way is inject the mailer service in InscriptionHandler using the http://jmsyst.com/bundles/JMSDiExtraBundle/master/annotations

Comment: Thanks user*, i guess that's what i need :)